# How do I edit crontab files with Vim (I get the error: 'temp file must be edited in place')?

Tags: save, unix

How do I edit `crontab` files in FreeBSD?

```
$ crontab -e
# ... I do my thing in vim & :wq

"crontab.9ZcXiFaawt" 6L, 203C written
crontab: temp file must be edited in place
Exit 1
```

Using `EDITOR=nvi` works fine... Linux also seems to work fine...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is how Vim writes files. By default, it makes a copy of the file and overwrite the original one.

You can observe this with:

```
# Show the file's inode
$ ls -i a
3156153 a

# Open file in Vim, :wq

# inode changed!
$ ls -i a
3155322 a
```

`crontab` gets confused by this (see `:help crontab`)

You need to use `:set backupcopy` to `yes` to make Vim overwrite the original file:

```
"yes"   make a copy of the file and overwrite the original one
```

You can do this automatically for crontab files with:

```
au FileType crontab setlocal bkc=yes
```

Answer (score 3):

@Martin's self-answer is correct. A variation though, for people like myself who try to limit populating their `vimrc` file with **occasional exceptions** -- here editing a crontab, is to use modelines. This allows to place the exceptions directly in the target file.

Below is my crontab modeline:

`# vim: nu et tw=130 ts=8 sts=4 sw=4 ff=unix fo-=l fo+=tcroq2 bkc=yes`

The important bit here is the `bkc=yes` which matches @Martin's `vimrc` configuration. The rest are personal convenience settings.

This said for completeness and food for thought, @Martin's initial answer is the most adequate in the majority of cases.

Answer (score 1):

Not the same error but also happening quite often:

```
Error detected while processing /root/.vimrc:
line    2:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: syntax enable
line    7:
...
```

This error will show up, if you use `vi` instead of `vim` for crontab.
You need to set the editor of crontab by adding the following code in your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export EDITOR=vim
```

Answer (score -1):

The same happens on OSX. After investigating the problem, I've found it works with plain `vi`, but it doesn't work with `vim`.

So the fix could be:

```
EDITOR=vi crontab -e
```

However `vi` is usually linked to `vim` (e.g. on OSX) so it's the same thing.

---

This can be solved by the following line in your *vimrc* file:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead crontab.* set nobackup | set nowritebackup
```

---

There is another workaround for this by adding the following lines to *.vimrc* file:

```
if $VIM_NOBACKUP
  set nobackup
  set nowritebackup
endif
```

and run the command:

```
VIM_NOBACKUP=1 crontab -e
```

You may also try to define the following variable:

```
EDITOR='VIM_NOBACKUP=1 vim'
```

Source: [crontab: temp file must be edited in place](http://drawohara.com/post/6344279/crontab-temp-file-must-be-edited-in-place)

---

The reason what this is happening has to do with the way `vim`/`vi` treats backup files.

Comment: Since `crontab` typically lifts the value of `EDITOR` or `VISUAL` (if it is defined), you can set them: `EDITOR='VIM_NOBACKUP=1 vim'`.

Comment: @muru I've tried, but I don't think it works. `crontab -e` generates `crontab: VIM_NOBACKUP=1 vim: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Must be an OSX thing, because it works on Arch Linux and Ubuntu, bash and zsh.

Comment: All the mucking about with environment variables seems silly to me; Vim has a way to deal with file-specific settings, and it's called autocmds. It looks like you just copied this from the link, but it seems that the author of that is not very familiar with Vim.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Thanks. I've re-arranged the solutions, so the easier one comes first. I've left environment variables just for reference/alternative way of doing it. `crontab.*` is enough, as `crontab -e` generates random files like `/tmp/crontab.X`.

Comment: Why include it at all? It's a silly way of doing things, and there's almost never a reason to not use an autocmd. When we remove that, we are left with just the autocmd, which is the same answer which has been here for over a month and a half. This answer adds nothing but noise.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Some people could have different problems and alternative solution could work or they just prefer this way. In example first part could not work if you've `vi` linked to `vim` (which you didn't include). And this is completely different answer to yours, so I don't get your point. Secondly in your answer you're changing inodes instead which is your reason to not use autocmd, which for me it only does the noise. Two different options/opinions are always good, unless you want to monopolize both Q&A.